# Kibana filter for 21pm to 9am

Tags: date, filter, timestamp, kibana

I have to analyze vpn log(only 21pm to 9am).

Is it possible to filtering time period on kibana dashboard?

Kibana version is 4.0

- Conditions.

  1. target log term : the first half of 2016
  2. time period : 21pm - 9am

Comment: Sure. but I don't know yet.

Answer (score 0):

If your index is configured with "Index contains time-based events" you can do so by using the Absolute panel of the time selector (top right icon).

The other solution is to add a filter using Range Query queries

```
{
    "range" : {
        "time" : {
            "gte": "2016-01-01 21:00",
            "lte": "2016-01-02 9:00"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hugodby. maybe my explanation was insufficient. I want to filter that 21pm - 9am every single days. For example 1/1 21:00 ~ 1/2 09:00 and 1/2 21:00 ~ 1/3 09:00 and 1/3 21:00 ~ 1/4 09:00...like this.

Comment: The only way to do that I think is to keep only the hours in a separate field and filter using what I gave you before.